# WriteProcessMemory returns 0 in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I am developing a small cash hack for `GTA V` and I found that when I use

```
WriteProcessMemory(hp, (LPVOID)0x1417C4C18, &cashVal, (DWORD)sizeof(cashVal), 0)
```

that the `WriteProcessMemory` returns 0. Here is the full source code of my small hack.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int cashVal = 0;
    cout << "Enter the amount of cash you want: " << endl;
    cin >> cashVal;

    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, "Grand Theft Auto V");
    if (hwnd == 0) {
        cout << "Cannot find the GTAV window. Make sure its running in Windowed mode!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        DWORD pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);
        HANDLE hp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pid);

        if (!hp) {
            cout << "Could not get a handle to GTAV. Try again :(" << endl;
        }
        else {
            int success = WriteProcessMemory(hp, (LPVOID)0x1417C4C18, &cashVal, (DWORD)sizeof

(cashVal), 0);

            if (success > 0) {
                cout << "You now have " << cashVal << " money!" << endl;
            }
            else {
                cout << "Writing the memory failed!" << endl;
                cout << "Error code: " << success << endl;
            }

            CloseHandle(hp);
        }
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I basically ask the user to input the cash they want, and it's meant to set it in the game, but it returns a code of 0 and fails. It doesn't fail trying to find the game window because it doesn't print that message to the standard output. Please help me!

NOTE: The hack will be used on single player

Comment: Try using `VirtualProtect` first to allow writing in that region. And use `GetLastError()` to see why it failed.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? If WriteProcessMemory returns zero, you're supposed to call GetLastError() to get error information. You're not doing so; you're cout'ing `success`, which you already know will be zero.

Comment: Why test `success > 0`? Where does it say that a positive return value indicates success? I suggest you read the documentation.

Comment: @Gill Bates Can you post an example of how to use VirtualProtect?

Comment: @GillBates: since the variable in question is tracking the player's money, it is presumably stored in writable memory so `VirtualProtect()` would not be needed to make it writable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it is not a tracking variable it simply sets the players money at that address (if you can think of a way to execute a function from another process please tell me!)

Comment: You should account the fact, that these PRO-games may have a sophisticated anti-debugging-technique implemented. Just FYI.

Comment: @dhillon232: the memory address represents a variable that is keeping track of the user's current money.  If the value of the money changes during the course of the game (and why wouldn't it?), the memory address would have to be writable (otherwise the game would not be able to save new values to it, especially when first loading the game).

Comment: @dhillon232: to execute a function in another process, you have to inject code into the process first, so it is running in the process's address space, then that code can call functions if it knows their memory addresses, calling conventions, parameters, etc. Being able to call functions using memory pointers is a fundamental feature of C and C++.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS`.  Only request what you actually need.  `WriteProcessMemory()` only needs `PROCESS_VM_WRITE` and `PROCESS_VM_OPERATION` access, so request only that.

Like many other API functions, when `WriteProcessMemory()` fails, `GetLastError()` will tell you why.  Your code is assuming that `WriteProcessMemory()` itself returns an error code directly, but it does not.  It returns a `BOOL` (not an `int`) to indicate success or failure, and then `GetLastError()` returns the error code if failure.  This is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674.aspx) behavior:

> Return value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is 0 (zero). **To get extended error information, call GetLastError**. The function fails if the requested write operation crosses into an area of the process that is inaccessible.

Try this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int cashVal = 0;
    cout << "Enter the amount of cash you want: " << endl;
    cin >> cashVal;

    HWND hwnd = FindWindow(0, "Grand Theft Auto V");
    if (hwnd == 0) {
        cout << "Cannot find the GTAV window. Make sure its running in Windowed mode!" << endl;
    }
    else {
        DWORD pid;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &pid);

        HANDLE hp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_WRITE | PROCESS_VM_OPERATION, FALSE, pid);    
        if (!hp) {
            cout << "Could not get a handle to GTAV. Try again :(" << endl;
        }
        else {
            BOOL success = WriteProcessMemory(hp, (LPVOID)0x1417C4C18, &cashVal, sizeof(cashVal), 0);
            if (success) {
                cout << "You now have " << cashVal << " money!" << endl;
            }
            else {
                DWORD errCode = GetLastError();
                cout << "Writing the memory failed!" << endl;
                cout << "Error code: " << errCode << endl;
            }

            CloseHandle(hp);
        }
    }

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try tommorow :)

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely trying to write to a memory path where you don't have access to... probably you are using a 32-bit program to write to a 64-bit memory address(that's if u use a 64-bit computer), I think I had this problem a few years back porting solved my problem then *forgive me if I am wrong* atleast that was what I thought.

Try the code on a 32-bit address and if it works... that solves your problem.

And for the Getting_Last_Error you can add this lil' bit of functionality I use.

```
void PrintLastErrorMsg(){
   LPTSTR pTmp = NULL;
   DWORD errnum = GetLastError();
   FormatMessage(
                FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER|FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM|FORMAT_MESSAGE_ARGUMENT_ARRAY,
                NULL, 
                errnum, 
                LANG_NEUTRAL,
                (LPTSTR)&pTmp, 
                0,
                NULL
                );

   cout << "Error(" << errnum << "): " << pTmp << endl;
}
```

Be free to make changes.